# `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

```
   create table wp_pageviews
    (
    ID BIGINT(20),
    count integer,
    primary key(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES wp_posts(ID)
    )
```

Error : `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint`

What is the reason for this? Why I can't create this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the `wp_posts(ID)` a `REFERENCE` for the `FOREIGN KEY`, you should also set the `wp_pageviews.ID`'s attributes as `UNSIGNED` and keep the same data type for the `wp_pageviews.ID` as (`bigint`) .

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: For those of us reading this, an explanation about why these steps are necessary would be helpful. Why does UNSIGNED solve the issue?